# python check if key already in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Parking Lot in OOP. i want to check if any key is already in my dictionary.
for example i dont want the same "plate number" in my dict.

I'm using the command:

```
    if plate in p1.carsAndEnterTime:
        print("This plate number already exists in the system")
        plate = input("Please enter the plate number:\n")
```

But it didnt found any key.

This is my full code:

```
class Cars:

    def __init__(self, phone, car_type, plate):
        self.__phone = phone
        self.__car_type = car_type
        self.__plate = plate

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__plate}, {self.__phone}, {self.__car_type}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__plate}, {self.__phone}, {self.__car_type}"


class ParkingLot:

    def __init__(self, name, capacity=1):
        ''' return a ParkingLot object with name "name" '''

        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.earnings = 0
        self.rate = 15
        self.carsAndEnterTime = {}

    def SetCapacity(self, newCap):
        ''' change the capacity from the default 1 '''
        if newCap < 1:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: parking lot size cannot be less than 1")

        self.capacity = newCap

    def GetCapacity(self):
        ''' return parking lot capacity '''
        return self.capacity

    def GetEarnings(self):
        ''' return how much much parking has made '''
        return self.earnings

    def VehicleEnters(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle enters parking lot'''
        # put car and its enter time in a dictionary
        self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle] = datetime.datetime.now()
        if self.capacity == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: Parking lot full!")
        self.capacity -= 1

    def SetSecondlyRate(self, rate=20):
        self.rate = rate

    def VehicleLeaves(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle leaves parking lot. when it leaves, charges money '''

        secondsDiff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        hour_roundup = math.ceil(secondsDiff.seconds / 3600)
        self.earnings += self.rate * hour_roundup
        # after earned money, delete vehicle from dictionary
        del self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        self.capacity += 1
```

When i do the following:

```
>>> p1 = ParkingLot(p1,2)
>>> plate = 12345
>>> car_type = "Public"
>>> phone = "05555555"
>>> c = c1 = Cars(plate, car_type, phone)
```

when i try to check if the palte inside the dict
but its ignores, Although palte exists dict.

```
 if plate in p1.carsAndEnterTime:
        print("This plate number already exists in the system")
        plate = input("Please enter the plate number:\n")
```

for example i print my dict:
and you can see the 12345 is found twise in my dict.

```
>>>print(p1.carsAndEnterTime)
{12345, 55555, p: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 10, 23, 0, 36, 557859), 12345, 5555, p: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 10, 23, 0, 44, 568150)}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: The keys in your dictionary are not ints but instances of `Cars`. 12345 is not a `Cars`, and it is not a key in that dictionary.

Comment: Also this is not [mre] code. We should be able to run and get the same results

Answer (score 2):

You do not put the cars into your parking lot by their Plate - you put full car-instances into your dictionary. If you put in 2 different car instances with the same values the `id(car1)` and `id(car2)` are different because 2 different objects. Hence no equality.

A crude way around that would be to check:

```
def CarAlreadyParked(self, vehicle):
    """Returns true if the exact car is already parked."""
    return any(str(c) == str(vehicle) for c in self.carsAndEnterTime)
```

before letting the car in - could be a forged identity car. All in all it would be better to redesign and maybe store cars by there plate in a dict:

```
dict [ PlateNr] = (VehicleInstance, CheckinTime)
```

so you can quickly find them by plateNr and have the vehicle-object in a tuple on the value